# Image picker plugin crashes when used with google place picker plugin

Tags: flutter

I am using google_places_picker: ^2.0.0 and image_picker: ^0.5.0+9 in my flutter project but the Image picker crashes after taking the picture.
This happens only when I am using places picker with image picker in my app. The image picker works fine without the place picker.

This happens in camera mode and not in gallery mode.

Below is the log for the error:

> E/AndroidRuntime(14439): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2343, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.flutterevents/com.example.flutterevents.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14439):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4382)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14439):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4426)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14439):    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(Unknown Source:0)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14439):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1685)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14439):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14439):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14439):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6626)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14439):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14439):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14439):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14439): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14439):    at io.flutter.view.FlutterNativeView$PlatformMessageHandlerImpl$1.reply(FlutterNativeView.java:197)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14439):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler$1.error(MethodChannel.java:209)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14439):    at com.theantimony.googleplacespicker.GooglePlacesPickerPlugin.onActivityResult(GooglePlacesPickerPlugin.kt:156)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14439):    at io.flutter.app.FlutterPluginRegistry.onActivityResult(FlutterPluginRegistry.java:210)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14439):    at io.flutter.app.FlutterActivityDelegate.onActivityResult(FlutterActivityDelegate.java:143)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14439):    at io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity.onActivityResult(FlutterActivity.java:142)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14439):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7305)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14439):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4378)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14439):    ... 9 more

Comment: Would you post your related code  ?

Comment: Code for getting the image: 

Future getImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    setState(() {
      _image = image;
    });
  }

Code for initialising place picker:
 PluginGooglePlacePicker.initialize(
      androidApiKey: "AIzaSyAHrDEUj-sFJ-pYJgqTCozcKAGpFAHSZTg",
      iosApiKey: "AIzaSyDN0soAKL4e9iDfb6oWom6ECnRCBpcWCvQ",
    );

Comment: I am initialising the place picker in the build method of my main class.